# On a RDS Farm memory ram Error - Debub file

Tags: excel, remote-server, remote-desktop, windows-server-2022

On a RDS Farm some users got a process (.excel) that consume memory ram untill machine stop, and restart. Its always excel, even if the user dont have any excel open (the process is there). I made a dump file of the process and i wanted to someone to look at it and give me some help or tell me what can i do to find what causes this and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

This is the dump file created with that process:

"KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

```
Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
Value: 25015

Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisManager
Value: Create

Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 698701

Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
Value: 343

Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
Value: 13575

Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
Value: 616

Key  : CLR.BuiltBy
Value: NET472REL1LAST_B

Key  : CLR.Engine
Value: CLR

Key  : CLR.Version
Value: 4.7.4051.0

Key  : Timeline.OS.Boot.DeltaSec
Value: 293765

Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
Value: 198

Key  : WER.OS.Branch
Value: rs5_release

Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
Value: 2018-09-14T14:34:00Z

Key  : WER.OS.Version
Value: 10.0.17763.1

Key  : WER.Process.Version
Value: 16.0.16626.20170
```

FILE_IN_CAB:  EXCEL.DMP

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  00007470

PROCESS_NAME:  EXCEL.EXE

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCE  O}  Ponto de interrup  o  Foi alcan ado um ponto de interrup  o.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

STACK_TEXT:
0000002c`c38fee38 00007ffc`d8cd8f52     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000010 0000002c`c38fe6f0 0000002c`c38fe7f0 : win32u!NtUserPeekMessage+0x14
0000002c`c38fee40 00007ffc`d8cd8e2e     : 00000000`00000002 000001af`8f0362e0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : user32!_PeekMessage+0x42
0000002c`c38feeb0 00007ffc`957ebe07     : 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : user32!PeekMessageW+0x9e
0000002c`c38fef20 00007ff6`684d7ac6     : 0000002c`c38ff090 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ff6`685118ed : mso20win32client!MsoPeekMessageW+0x27
0000002c`c38fef60 00007ff6`684d79ca     : 0000002c`c38fef80 0000002c`c38ff080 00000000`00000000 000001af`8ea63090 : EXCEL!PeekMessageU+0xf4
0000002c`c38ff020 00007ff6`684d74cd     : 00007ff6`6851176a 0000137f`00001f80 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : EXCEL!PeekMessageXl+0x4e
0000002c`c38ff060 00007ff6`68575c65     : 0000002c`c38ff1b0 0000002c`c38ff200 000001af`8ea63090 0000002c`c38ff240 : EXCEL!_FGetEvt2+0x8d
0000002c`c38ff140 00007ff6`684d9445     : 00000000`00000019 00000000`0000008d 000001af`8ea63090 00000000`00000000 : EXCEL!MainLoop+0x5a5
0000002c`c38ff860 00007ff6`685787f9     : 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : EXCEL!WinMain+0xaa5
0000002c`c38ffb40 00007ffc`d9747ac4     : 00000000`00000000 00007ff6`684ba070 0000002c`c3638000 00007ff6`684ba070 : EXCEL!_imp_load_RmGetList+0x205
0000002c`c38ffb80 00007ffc`daf4a351     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
0000002c`c38ffbb0 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21

STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32u!NtUserPeekMessage+14

MODULE_NAME: win32u

IMAGE_NAME:  win32u.dll

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_80000003_win32u.dll!NtUserPeekMessage

OS_VERSION:  10.0.17763.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs5_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.17763.4720

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {62030ec8-14d0-9919-70d3-cbaa3c2f4413}

Followup:     MachineOwner"

- update excel
- the excel files are diferent, and dont seem to have any connection to each other